# Exporting a single project from an SVN repository

Tags: svn, migration, merge

I'm storing several projects under the same SVN repository. I've followed the manual and did this: I `svnadmin dump c:\repository | svndumpfilter include <my project> > myproject.dump`.

My problem is, svndumpfilter chokes with the error "Invalid copy source path", because we moved that particular project from branches back to another folder a while ago.

Has anyone dealt with this particular problem successfully?

I am currently thinking of dumping the main repository in chunks, skipping the revisions that may cause errors. I will then load each chunk into the new repository, each chunk under a folder, and merge them using Eclipse. Does this sound sane to you? Do you see any problems with it?

Answer (score 0):

How was this project moved?  There is an [`svn move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) command that can be used to move files/directories and, more important, let Subversion know that said files/directories have been moved.

```
svn move -m "Moved old/dir to new/dir" file:///url/to/old/dir file:///url/to/new/dir
```

Since you've already moved it, I suggest you try using [`svn delete`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html) on the project's old location. This *should* force Subversion to remove references to the old location:

```
svn delete -m "Project was moved some time ago, reflecting in repository" file:///url/to/old/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
svnadmin dump c:\repository | svndumpfilter include project > myproject.dump
```

This will include everything below the project.

For more details, I added the svndumpfilter help.

```
$ svndumpfilter help include
include: Filter out nodes without given prefixes from dumpstream.
usage: svndumpfilter include PATH_PREFIX...

Valid options:
  --drop-empty-revs        : Remove revisions emptied by filtering.
  --renumber-revs          : Renumber revisions left after filtering.
  --skip-missing-merge-sources : Skip missing merge sources.
  --targets ARG            : Pass contents of file ARG as additional args
  --preserve-revprops      : Don't filter revision properties.
  --quiet                  : Do not display filtering statistics.
```